# How do I compare a string with key value in dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

How do I compare a string with key value in dictionary? Suppose my dictionary keys are "f001.name", "f002.item", and "f003.content", and I need to find out the keys which have only "foo1" in it.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are trying to filter out list of values from your dictionary?

You can try below code, it will filter out those pair with Key contains "f001":

```
Dictionary<string, string> filterValues = myValues.Where(s =>    s.Key.Contains("f001")).ToDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is not a good choice if you have to iterate it.   It's meant for direct, fast object lookup based on a hash key value.

If you want to go through the different values to evaluate them, a List is probably a better choice.

A dictionary *does* have an IEnumerable interface, so you can use foreach to traverse all the entries.  You'll have to declare a type-appropriate KeyValuePair to use in the iterator, but it's all pretty strightforward from there.

As an example:

```
   foreach( KeyValuePair<string, myObjectType) kvp in MyDictionary)
       if (kvp.Key.Contains("foo") then System.Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keys in Dictionary are unique so there will be only one `foo1` key in dictionary.

You iterate on a collection when there are more than one value.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the list of the keys and return if the specific key with the sub string is found

```
foreach(string key in myDictonary.Keys)
  if(key.Contains("yourString"))
     //return key
```